# Access 97 creating object from VB

Tags: ms-access

In access 97, is it possible to add some element to the form using VB, like some command button whose caption is "Hello Word" and which height is 300 and width 700?

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. What's your REAL question? What have you tried and what isn't working for you?

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, it might be easier to just create a hidden button and then use VBA to show/hide it at runtime.  Me.CommandButton.Visible = True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Function AddCommandButtonFunction()
Dim btn As CommandButton

DoCmd.OpenForm "TestForm", acDesign

On Error Resume Next
DeleteControl "TestForm", "NewButton"

On Error GoTo lberr
Set btn = CreateControl("TestForm", acCommandButton)

btn.Name = "NewButton"
btn.Caption = "Hello World!"
btn.Top = 500 'twips. 1 twip = 1/1440 in
btn.Left = 500 'twips
btn.Width = 2000 'twips
btn.Height = 500 'twips

DoCmd.Close acForm, "TestForm", acSaveYes
DoCmd.OpenForm "TestForm", acNormal

Exit Function

lberr:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Function
```

Please note adding/deleting of control (programmatically) is **only** allowed in Design mode